# Loop through files by modified date in C#

Tags: c#

The user is selecting multiple files

```
  OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
  openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
  DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
  int id = RadarGraphInsertDLL.SalesDWH.Return_Last_QuickLabDumpID();
  if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
  {
      foreach (string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
      {
         /////
```

I would like the `foreach` to work on the files in order of MODIFIED DATE

How do I grab the files by modified date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this to order the list of files:

```
openFileDialog1.FileNames.OrderBy(p => System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(p))
```

**EDIT - Ordering clarification**

In this case, `.OrderBy` will order the file names in terms of the oldest modified file first.  To order in terms of the most recently modified file first, use `.OrderByDescending` instead.

Comment: @I__, just use OrderByDescending.  I edited my answer above to show this.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT :** sorry, I misread the question.

[`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class provides the necessary property to get the modified date.
For the sorting part you can use LINQ [`OrderBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx), e.g.:

```
var sortedFiles = 
openFileDialog1.FileNames.OrderBy(x => new FileInfo(x).LastWriteTime);

foreach(var file in sortedFiles)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your input. i want the files to be sorted by modified date before the FOREACH

Comment: They're the same. I just forgot that there is a static method in `File` class as well to get the date :) However, probably  @AdamS solution is slighlty better because avoids the creation of a throwaway `FileInfo` object.